# Evaluate $\int(\tan^2x+\tan^4x)dx$

Tags: calculus

So, I figured out that $$\int\tan^2xdx =\int(\sec^2x-1)dx=\tan x-x+C$$

I'm trying to adapt this so I can also evaluate $\int\tan^4x$.

Comment: What's the derivative of $\tan^3x$?

Comment: HaKuNa MaTaTa, you have over 5k rep. You should know how to format trig functions in MathJax by now. Please review the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original integral is
$$
\int\tan^2x\sec^2x\:dx=\tfrac13\tan^3x+C.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\int (\tan^2(x))(1 + \tan^2(x)) dx = \int (\tan^2 x)(\sec^2 x)\,dx = \int \tan^2x (\tan x)' dx = \frac 13 \tan^3 x + C$$

Comment: I think it's more direct than this, as $1+tan^2(x)=sec^2(x)$, thanks though!!!

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa amWhy's penultimate step confirms this with the derivative of $\tan^2 x$

Comment: @amWhy its $(tanx)'$ and not $(tan^2x)'$ :)

Comment: @Kevin you got me wrong! It was inititally $tan^2x$ so I suggested an edit :) And 'why ' is a part of the username ;)

Comment: @DatBoi LOL I'll remove my comment! Thanks!